# Помогите обнаружить причину низкого фпс на эмуляторе

Tags: android-studio, avd

была простенькая игрушка , выдавала за  150 фпс на эмуляторе андроид с HAXM , при включении эмулятора где то всегда была надпись что включен HAXM . ПРошло время , игрушка немного усложнилась, но на телефоне по прежнему за 100 фпс , а на эмуляторе как ни крути не более 15. Что интересно я отключаю полностью отрисовку графики, отключаю алгоритмы обнаружения коллизий и на телефоне фпс около 1000 - 500 скачет, а на эмуляторе прибавляется всего пару кадров.. Удалил уже и HAXM и сам эмулятор в SDK manager , заново установил , не забыл зайти в папку extras и установить HAXM задав рекомендуемый RAM  в 2 Gb . Но ничего не помогает.  Где то прочитал, что без NAXM эмулятор толком с ютуба видео не грузит . Проверил, включил видео , никаких слайдшоу. в командной строке в виндвос ввожу команду и вижу что NAXM включен, в биосе тоже всё включено.  Какие еще можно провести эксперименты? Алгоритм проверки фпс работает , так как любые изменения в отрисовке или в ограничении кадров работают на реальном устройстве .

И кстати при включении эмулятора нигде не могу найти сообщение о том , что HAXM работает. Но это  и не важно, так как иначе устройства с образом x86 не запустились бы.

**UPD**
Вопрос сводится вот к чему : имеется два эмулятора от AVD , на одном fullHd разрешение , на другом 400x800 , в остальном они похожи. Запускаю приложение на тест предварительно отключив любую прорисовку, работает лишь несколько алгоритмов и на эмуляторе с меньшим разрешением экрана , fps значительно выше. В чем причина не могу понять..
На реальном устройстве отключение прорисовки дает прирост фпс в 10 раз, а на эмуляторе прироста вообще нет..с чем может быть связано?

Comment: обнаружил, что если полностью отключить прорисовку графики ( отображается просто белый экран, никаких перерисовок) , но включить это на эмуляторе с экраном 400х800 то фпс куда выше, чем если на full hd экране. Только я не понимаю, почему это имеет влияние , если я ничего не рисую?   фпс подскакивает с 20 до 100

Comment: это не только у вас) эмулятор для более-менее сложных вещей (в т.ч. с HAXM) всегда идет с тормозами. по этой причине тестирую все на реальном устройстве, эмуляторы только для проверки по разрешению экрана. попробуйте вместо эмулятора android studio эмуляторы сторонних разработчиков, они быстрее.

Comment: И что же у нас есть от сторонних разработчиков? GenyMotion, который является перекрашеным VirtualBox с красивыми бантиками? http://emulation.gametechwiki.com/index.php/Android_emulators - тут хоть что-то есть съедобное?

Comment: Да, действительно , я разбирал эту тему и вывод таков , что если поддерживается HAXM , то сторонние эмуляторы далеко позади. GenyMotion решение для тех кто без поддержки HAXM.